# Affix not working when adding multiple column sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using bootstrap 3.3.5, jquery 1.11.3 and the affix script to try to keep my navigation bar at the top of my screen at all times.  It has been working well except when I try to add columns with the col-xs-* and col-md-* classes.

For example it scrolls fine with multiple containers in rows like this:

```
<div id="container" class="container-fluid">
   <div id="about" class="container-fluid">
     <!--some information here, it scrolls fine-->
   </div>
 <div id="resume" class="container-fluid">
   <div class="container-fluid">
     <!--seemingly the problem has to do with using the xs and md tags-->
     <div class="row" style="background-color:lavender;">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-md-8</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
     </div>
     <div class="row" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
     </div>
        <div class="row" style="background-color:lightcyan;">
          <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="projects_sidescroller" class="container-fluid">
  <!--this one scrolls fine as well-->
</div>
```

I have set up a jsfiddle link with the problem present.  When you scroll down to the coloured table, it's text will display on top the navbar instead of hiding below it.  https://jsfiddle.net/mhjyw37d/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `z-index` to your affix class.

Like:

```
.affix {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfect.  Do you have a little more information on the z-index?

Comment: z-index: 1; is enough, avoid big value.